# Colouring grep pattern match with a preferred colour

Tags: bash, grep, colors

I am using the following pattern matching to colour in a preferred colour using `tput`.

```
 | sed -r $"s/^==> .* <==$/$(tput setaf 46)&$(tput sgr0)/"
```

I wonder if I can do a similar thing with 'grep'

```
| $_GREP -e ^ -e '^==>.*'
```

with

```
_GREP="/bin/grep --color"
```

Am not quite sure how to incorporate a preferred colour on the grep matching.

Comment: GNU `grep` has built-in support for highlighting the match with user-defined colors. See its manual page, especially around the `GREP_COLORS` environment variable.

Comment: Seems that the grep colours have to be global, rather than changing them at will as one can do with `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: yeah probably cuz grep is a bit older :D

Comment: @Red Environment variables are per-process. They get inherited, so you can conveniently set up a default, which you can override for each and every process individually if you wish to. Just say `env GREP_COLORS=... grep ...`, or inside shell scripts simply `GREP_COLORS=... grep ...`.

Comment: ... or `export GREP_COLORS=...` if you want it to take effect for the rest of your shell script, i.e. all the `grep` command you'll invoke from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
export GREP_COLOR='1;37;31'
grep -E --color=auto -i '{texttofind}' /dir/to/file
```

Color is added via [ANSI escape sequences.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) See the FG and BG section in the middle (1 is background, 37 white, 31 red)

Comment: I have been able to use `| GREP_COLOR='01;36' $_GREP -e ^ -e '^==> .* <==$'`.  Although this does not work with `GREP_COLORS`.  I cannot use `tput` either.

Comment: @Red is that a problem? If this works, why not use this?

Comment: It has been deprecated in favor of `GREP_COLORS`.